# Search, modify and replace text

Tags: python, function, search, replace

I want a simple method to find a pattern in a string and modify it

I have a multiline text and I want to modify all the values that are double quotes (")

For example, between double quotes there are only characters, and I want to add 5 in their ascii value and modify the letters

```py
def printChar(char):
    x = ord(char)
    x += 5
    return(chr(x))
```

In this way if I have "a", I want to put "f", how do I make a replace that lets me put an intermediate function?

Comment: Can you provide a sample text?

Comment: Before replacing anything, you should think about how you'd _find_ a character that's between two double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using regex and lambda. The regex might need some tweaking. Right now it requires at least one character between the double quotes (otherwise the first one is ignored) and what's between them double quotes has to be alphanumeric.

```
import re
t = 'This is "ABCD" or "EFGH"'

re.sub(r'"[A-Za-z0-9]+"', lambda x: ''.join(chr(ord(c)+5) for c in x.group(0)), t)
```

Output

```
"This is 'FGHI' or 'JKLM'"
```